# Plotting frequency counts of ordinal variables

Tags: r

I have a rather formidable questionnaire (2000 participants) which is split into 86 geographic regions (KPGs). This will be part of a broader study of land use change, so I need to visualize the frequency of every answer for every KPG to get "a feel for my data". the answers are questionaire answers, so they are ordinal or nominal data (which the online survey company turns into numbers).

```
 KPG Q1 Q2 Q3
1  112 -1  5  4
2  112  5  5  4
3  112  1  5  4
4  112  2  5  4
5  111  3  3  4
6  111  4  3 -1
7  111  2  3  2
8  111  2  3  3
9  111  2  3  5
10 111  2  3  5
11 113  2  3  5
12 113  2 -1  5
13 113  1  2  5
14 113 -1  2  5
15 113 -1  5  5
16 113  4  2  5

plot(table(test$Q1))
```

gives me a frequency count for question 1 over ALL KPGs

Now how do I get this plot broken down into every KPG?

```
plot(table(Q1~KPG, data="test")
```

ends in an error, which I thought it would. But I can't seem to wrap my head around how to get the correct plot.

I have (with help from stackoverflow) managed to get a frequency count

```
FREQTEST<-do.call("cbind", lapply(names(test[-1]), function(x) { temp <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(test[["KPG"]], test[[x]])); setNames(temp, paste0(x, names(temp))) }))
```

Results in a correct frequency count for all questions BY the grouping factor (KPG).

```
Q1-1 Q11 Q12 Q13 Q14 Q15 Q2-1 Q22 Q23 Q25 Q3-1 Q32 Q33 Q34 Q35
111    0   0   4   1   1   0    0   0   6   0    1   1   1   1   2
112    1   1   1   0   0   1    0   0   0   4    0   0   0   4   0
113    2   1   2   0   1   0    1   3   1   1    0   0   0   0   6
```

So I could work from this as well

I expect something like a barchart, with one bar per answer, where the height of every answer results is the frequency that answer was given.

Comment: With `ggplot` you can do: `ggplot(test, aes(Q1, fill = factor(KPG))) + geom_bar()`, or with base R: `barplot(test$Q1, col = factor(test$KPG))`

Comment: Thank you, this is a good start... however in my "real" data I have 86 rows and 40 columns

Comment: So is there a way to get an individual plot for every question and every KPG without all the unncessary typing?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be a starting point: you can use `dplyr`, `ggplot2` to work the data and plot them.

However, here the code:

```
# first, I used your function to have the frequencies:
ftest <- do.call("cbind", lapply(names(test[-1]), function(x) { temp <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(test[["KPG"]], test[[x]])); setNames(temp, paste0(x, names(temp))) }))

# then I added the KPG as column, not as rownames
ftest$KPG <- rownames(ftest)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# now the work on the data, and the plot, in a dplyr chain
gather(ftest, variable, value, -KPG) %>%  # from wide to long format
ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) +    # add plot, faced by kpg
geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
facet_wrap(vars (KPG))
```

[image]

And you can customize it as you prefere.

---

With data:

```
test <- read.table(text = "KPG Q1 Q2 Q3
1  112 -1  5  4
2  112  5  5  4
3  112  1  5  4
4  112  2  5  4
5  111  3  3  4
6  111  4  3 -1
7  111  2  3  2
8  111  2  3  3
9  111  2  3  5
10 111  2  3  5
11 113  2  3  5
12 113  2 -1  5
13 113  1  2  5
14 113 -1  2  5
15 113 -1  5  5
16 113  4  2  5",header = T)
```